How do you get rank XP in Trackmania 2020?
Trackmania 2020 has a ranked mode where you compete in a 3v3 setting. However, even when my team wins, I don’t get any XP. It’s worth nothing that I haven’t been MVP yet.
How do I get XP from ranked? Do I have to be MVP?

From the trackmania docs (which are apparently a thing), You most likely end 3rd when losing and 4th when winning, counterbalancing the team bonus/malus:

In an average match where both teams are of equal skill, the point distribution is as follows:

Overall player position     Points gained
1st                         +30
2nd                         +20
3rd                         +10
4th                         -10
5th                         -20
6th                         -30


Players of the winning team gain an additional +10 points, players of the losing team lose an additional -10 points.


Note that imbalanced matches may yield a different amount of ranking points per player depending on the players' rankings.


The player who scored the most points in the entire match, no matter whether they are on the winning or losing side, is the Match MVP and earns bonus rating points. The amount of bonus MVP points depends on the skill bracket the player is in and how evenly skilled the teams are. The values below assume evenly matched teams:

Skill bracket      MVP bonus points
Bronze             +80
Silver and above   +40

